# How to change Image color type using Piston's image lib?

Tags: rust

I have an application intended to work with image data using RGB pixel formats. I need to allow it to take images of all encodings. My first idea was to convert the image to RGB format before processing:

```
extern crate image;

use std::ops;
use image::ConvertBuffer;

pub fn process_generic<P,C>(im: image::ImageBuffer<P,C>)
   where P: image::Pixel + 'static,
         P::Subpixel: 'static,
         C: ops::Deref<Target = [P::Subpixel]>
{
    let result: image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgb<u8>, Vec<u8>> = im.convert();
}

fn main() {}
```

Compiling this gives me an error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `image::Rgb<u8>: image::color::FromColor<P>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:12:66
   |
12 |     let result: image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgb<u8>, Vec<u8>> = im.convert();
   |                                                                  ^^^^^^^ the trait `image::color::FromColor<P>` is not implemented for `image::Rgb<u8>`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where image::Rgb<u8>: image::color::FromColor<P>` bound
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `image::ConvertBuffer<image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgb<u8>, std::vec::Vec<u8>>>` for `image::ImageBuffer<P, C>`
```

I can't add the bound because the module `image::color` is private. Am I missing something? I was also attempting to go through and convert each pixel manually, but that seems like a worse way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the trait bound provided by `image::ConvertBuffer` directly:

```
extern crate image;

use image::ConvertBuffer;

pub fn process_generic<P, C>(im: image::ImageBuffer<P, C>)
where
    image::ImageBuffer<P, C>: image::ConvertBuffer<image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgb<u8>, Vec<u8>>>,
    P: image::Pixel + 'static,
{
    let _result = im.convert();
}

fn main() {}
```

Although I'd recommend introducing a type alias for `image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgb<u8>, Vec<u8>>` and/or `image::ImageBuffer<P, C>`.

Comment: Aha, thanks! There is an alias "RgbImage" that I usually use, but I figured it'd be useful to state it explicitly. However, I'm not sure how to alias ImageBuffer<P,C> because I'd still need the `where` clause in my functions (I keep getting `trait constraints in type definitions not enforced`)

Comment: Yeah, including the full example in the question is definitely the right thing to do. There's not much you can do for the `image::ImageBuffer<P, C>`; really I meant you might want to just import it fully to avoid writing "image" twice `.